# Python dash dataTable style_cell_conditional - multiple conditions

Tags: python, datatable, conditional-formatting

I want to set 2 conditions in `style_cell_conditional`. The code below doesn't work.

Error:SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

```
dash_table.DataTable(
                     id='table1',
                     columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_table13.columns],
                     style_cell_conditional=[
                                            {
                                            'if': {'column_id': i},
                                            'backgroundColor': '#B10DC9',
                                            'color': 'white'
                                            }for i in df_table13.columns if i!='index',

                                            {'if': {'column_id': 'index'},
                                             'width': '200px'
                                            }
                                            ]
                     data=df_table13.to_dict('records')

)
```

If I put only one condition with for loop then it works:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
                     id='table1',
                     columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_table13.columns],
                     style_cell_conditional=[
                                            {
                                            'if': {'column_id': i},
                                            'backgroundColor': '#B10DC9',
                                            'color': 'white'
                                            }for i in df_table13.columns if i!='index'
                                            ]
                     data=df_table13.to_dict('records')

)
```

also works when I put two conditions, but without for loop:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
                     id='table1',
                     columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_table13.columns],
                     style_cell_conditional=[
                                                                                           
                                            {'if': {'column_id': 'index'},
                                             'width': '200px'
                                            },

                                            {'if': {'column_id': 'column2'},
                                             'color': 'white'
                                            }
                                            ]
                     data=df_table13.to_dict('records')

)
```

How can I combine condition like:

```
                                        {'if': {'column_id': 'column2'},
                                         'color': 'white'
                                        }
```

with condition like:

```
                                   {
                                    'if': {'column_id': i},
                                    'backgroundColor': '#B10DC9',
                                    'color': 'white'
                                    }for i in df_table13.columns if i!='index'
```

Or how to use the **inequality** expression below? It would solve my problem.

```
   {'if': {'column_id': 'index'},
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to concatenate the two arrays:

```
[
    {
        'if': {'column_id': 'column2'},
        'color': 'white'
    }
] + [
    {
        'if': {'column_id': i},
        'backgroundColor': '#B10DC9',
        'color': 'white'
    }for i in df_table13.columns if i!='index'
]
```